# Am unable to get the Data from bundle in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In my app, i need to send a Two dimensional Array and two more integer values form on Activity  to Another with the help of Intent method.
This is done as ..

```
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
            Bundle postbundle = new Bundle();
            String[][] X={{"abc"},{"def"}};
            postbundle.putSerializable("data", X);
            i.putExtra("A", postbundle);

            i.putExtra("albumid", position);
            i.putExtra("Bigcard",bigcard);
```

here am using    .putSerializable  method to place an array into bundle.

So to access these data in the receiver Activity am using

```
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("A");       
    String[][] ABC=(String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("data");
    Log.e("Array is",""+ABC);
```

but I got  `java.lang.NullPointerException` error message..

Whith out use of  "   **Static** " declaration how can i get these values from bundle here (in the receiver Activity..)

Let me out pls from this ..

Comment: I am not very sure because I don't have a testing environment with me, but you may try `getBundleExtra(String name)` to get the bundle in your second activity. Then get the array using appropriate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step-1:Write a seperate bean class and save into another file

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
String[][] data = null;
public void set2DArray(String[][] data){
    this.data = data;
}
public String[][] get2DArray(){
    return data;
 }
}
```

step-2:In the calling activity

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);

   String data[][] = new String[][] {{"1","kumar"},{"2","sona"},{"3","kora"},{"1","pavan"},{"2","kumar"},{"3","kora333"}};
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.set2DArray(data);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("mybean", bean);
    intent.putExtra("obj", b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

step-3:In the caller activity

```
        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("obj");
       MyBean dData = (MyBean) b.getSerializable("mybean");
       String[][] str =dData.get2DArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but a try:

what happens if You try:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int a = intent.getIntExtra("albumid"); //if Your value is an int, otherwise use String
                                           //getStringExtra or whatever Your value is
```

Comment: its good but here my requirement is " accessing the 2D Array...ie, data "